# Trabalhar com erros dentro de loop em R

Tags: r, loop

Inseri a função de ajuste não-linear `gnls` dentro de um `loop for` para que pudesse testar uma série de `start values` automaticamente.

A questão é que eventualmente algum desses `start values` geram erro na rotina `gnls`.

O que preciso é fazer com que, em caso de erro, o `loop` recomece com o próximo valor, ignorando o problema.

Algo como `on error goto next`, mas não há essa sintaxe em R.

Comment: veja `?tryCatch()`

Comment: Muito obrigado, @djas! Tá funcionando!

Comment: @djas coloque seu comentário como uma resposta, abs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicando brevemente a sugestão do djas (coloquei como wiki da comunidade).

Uma forma de resolver o seu problema é utilizando o `try()` ou `tryCatch()`.

Por exemplo o código abaixo vai parar em `i+"a"` por causa do erro e não vai realizar o `print`:

```
for(i in 1:10){
  i + "a"
  print(i)
}
```

Colocando `try()` o código continua mesmo com o erro.

```
for(i in 1:10){
  try(i + "a")
  print(i)
}
```